# Saving String information into SQL Server CE database in Visual Basic 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have a problem with my code... It works but only when I type in random letters and numbers. It won't save actual information like names and addresses.

Here is the code for it. The SQL code is a bit long because there is a lot of data being entered.

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO Studentsnew(lname,fname,mname,sex,citizenship,religion,dbirth,pbirth,Address,cityaddress,provaddress,zipcode,telnum,cellnum,Nameoffather,FatherStatus,FatherNationality,FatherAddress,FatherReligion,NameofMother,MotherStatus,MotherNationality,MotherReligion,MotherAddress,MaritalStatus) VALUES (@lname,@fname,@mname,@sex,@citizenship,@relgion,@dbirth,@pbirth,@Address,@cityaddress,@provaddress,@zipcode,@telnum,@cellnum,@Nameoffather,@FatherStatus,@FatherNationality,@FatherAddress,@FatherReligion,@NameofMother,@MotherStatus,@MotherNationality,@MotherReligion,@MotherAddress,@MaritalStatus);", con)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtLname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtFname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", txtMname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", gender)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@citizenship", txtNat.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@relgion", txtRel.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbirth", txtBday.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pbirth", txtPoB.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAd1.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cityaddress", txtAd2.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@provaddress", txtAd3.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zipcode", txtZipCode.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telnum", txtTelephone.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellnum", txtCellphone.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nameoffather", txtFatname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherStatus", fstatus)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherNationality", txtFatnat.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherAddress", txtFatad.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FatherReligion", txtFatrel.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameofMother", txtMotname.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherStatus", mstatus)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherNationality", txtMotnat.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherReligion", txtmotrel.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MotherAddress", txtMotad.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", marital)

    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then con.Open()

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

Already fixed... changed the `cmd.Parameters` codes to be like this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lname", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = txtLname.Text
```